# Joomla categories - how to organize them and how to do Menus

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla2.5, categories

The site on J2.5 i am building will have many categories... lets take cooking for the analogy....

for now it is organized like this:

MAIN DISHES 1

-Dish1

-Dish2

-Dish3

---Dish3 sub1

---Dish3 sub2

---Dish3 sub3

---Dish3 sub4

-Dish4

- ....

I will have like 7-8 MAIN DISHES with each of them having approx. 40 Dishes, and each of those approx. 5 subdishes... those were all categories, now have to be populated with articles...

First question, is there any way to simplify that organization? Maybe not to have MAIN DISHES at all, just a big nuber of Dishes with its subcategories...

Secondly, how to organize the menus? Having the menu with 200 Dishes seems very non-ergonomical... maybe make alphabetical subgroups (like A-D, E-H, I-M, etc.?)

Third, i would like the submenu od Subdishes appear on the sepparate template position, WHEN that Dish is navigated to... if you understand what i am saying... the main menu having MAIN DISH - Dish, and then, on the left appears Sub1, sub2, sub3 when i navigate to Dish. Do i really have to create a new menu for every Dish or can the menu be somehow dynamicaly populated with Subdishes, based on the category selected?

I think this is all for now... based on you respected answers, i might have a few additional questions.

Thanks

EDIT: just crossed my mind, maybe just one category and Tag-Based menus, if something like that exists like a component...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would really recommend for you to use Joomla3 and not Joomla2.5. Main Joomla3 advantage is responsive default templates. These are not too bad and works great on desktops and mobile phones. What template are you using in Joomla 2.5? Is it custom one, created by you or are you using the default one from Joomla installation package?

Probably the main issue with categories is that article (dish) **can have only one category**. I think you will be hassling one day with some dish - in which category to put it in? Remember, you are allowed to select only one category.

With tags you can solve this problem. Any dish could have any number of tags. So I would suggest for you to use tags instead of categories. I am quite sure you could find descent extension where you could manage tags in Joomla2.5, but tags are **built-in Joomla3**. In Joomla3 there is component called tags. In this component you even can create sub-tags (parent and child tags), so I think it would totally fit you.

About menu items. Well you don't have to create menu item for each dish. What you could do is to organise dishes (articles) into categories (tags) and then create links only for categories (tags). For example you have a category (tag) called *soups*. Then you create a link for *soups* category (tag) and in that link there will be shown all dishes (articles) which are in *soups*. Visitor will be able to press on each of them and get into dish article for more information. So when you are creating a link look for menu item called *category blog list* or just *category list*. In Joomla3 you can create menu item which displays *compact list of tagged items*.

So I hope I gave you wide view of possibilities, but I think the best approach is to use *tags* component in Joomla3. Create menu items called *compact list of tagged items*. And the use tags module to show all the tags listed somewhere and don't categorise articles too much. Maybe just few categories for your own comfort.

If you really really care about SEO (Search Engine Optimization), then you should create menu item for each dish. Just because of SEF (Search Engine Friendly) links which are created for each menu item. If article doesn't have a link then there will be used generic Joomla link for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I am using a custom responsive template from gavick which works well on both desktop and mobile platforms. Also, for handling articles and categories, i hve dived into K2, because of tags and article organization.
I have been menaing to switch to 3.0, but i would like to keep 2.5 until there is a new LTS version. then i plan on upgrading the template as well as the platform.
Also, there is a K2 extension allowing me to add a secondary category to the article...

Comment: Oh, sounds great. Looks like you are doing well on your own :) I am not familiar with K2, but I am sure you will be fine with creating menu items for categories' lists. Also don't forget to include somewhere in website the list of categories itself. I am sure you can find a module for this.

Comment: You mean something like SiteMap? i did that already :)
Are you maybe familiar with any limitations of Joomla 2.5 regarding the number of menus/menu items and the number of categories?

Comment: [Max Categories number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15605240/1353644)

No, I don't mean sitemap. For example: [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) Look on the left column called "categories". It is put there using module which shows the whole list of categories.

Answer (score 0):

You've already switched to K2, so I don't have to recommend that. As for structure of the menus, each menu item should link to a category only. You do not need to create menu items for each dish, they will inherit the itemID from the category they are in. The URLS will look like this for a dish -

domain.com/category menu item alias/sub category menu item alias/dish K2 item alias.html

This assumes you use the built in Joomla SEF URLs with mod_rewrite and append .html.

As for your menus, you don't need to create a menu for each of the menus you want on the left. All you need to do is use a single menu module that is set to display a start level of 2 and an end level of something higher than 2. What this tells Joomla is to display the sub-menus for the currently selected parent menu item. So if you click on Dish3 in the main menu, the left menu will display all of the child menus for Dish3. Make sense? You may need to adjust the start level for the left menu depending on how you set up your menus.